# Finding special presentations for finite groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, gap, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group.
Call a presentation of $G$ "normalised" (I do not know whether such presentations by generators and relations have been studied before and I invented the name "normalised" here) if it is of the form

$$\langle x_1,...,x_n \mid  x_i^{r_i}=1, \ i=1,...,n ; v_t(x_1,....,x_n)=w_t(x_1,...,x_n) , t=1,...,u\rangle. $$

Here $x_i$ are generators (so that we can not omit any $x_i$) with $r_i \geq 2$ their order and the $v_t$ and $w_t$ are words in the $x_i$ of length at least two (We really want them to be words in the $x_i$ that do not contain inverses of the elements $x_i$).

Examples:

- $G=\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has the normalised presentation $\langle x_1 ,x_2 \mid x_1^m=1 , x_2^n=1 , x_1 x_2=x_2 x_1 \rangle$.
- The standard  presentation for the dicyclic group ($n=2$ gives the quaternion group) $\langle x_1 , x_2 \mid x_1^{2n}=1 , x_2^{2n}=1 , x_1^n= x_2^2 , x_2 x_1 x_2^{-1} = x_1^{-1} \rangle $ is not "normalised" since in $x_2 x_1 x_2^{-1} = x_1^{-1}$ there appear inverses.

> Question: Is there a standard procedure to obtain a normalised presentation for a given finite group (it seems they always exist)? Can one add additional hypothesis on the "normalised" condition to make such a presentation unique with some special properties (one nice condition might be that all generators have the "smallest possible" orders)?

It would also be interesting whether it is possible to obtain normalised presentations using GAP. It would also be interesting to know for which finite groups $G$, there exists such a normalised presentation where all generators have order two. Maybe someone knows a reference for that.

Comment: Once you have relations $x^r=1$, you can replace $x^-1$ by $x^{r-1}$. so you always can get this form. But it will be far from standardized. Even in the almost easiest case of metacyclic groups, there will have to be choices made and the only universal decision criterion I can imagine would be to enumerate all and pick a lexicographic smallest one.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. One interesting condition might be that generators have very small order (like in the Coxeter case). In that sense the presentation for the dicyclic groups is rather bad.

Comment: I think you still will get a lot of choice and thus messy relations. For example $A_5$ has 19 different 3-generating sets with elements of order 2 by  `f:=FreeGroup(3);;g:=f/[f.1^2,f.2^2,f.3^2];q:=GQuotients(g,AlternatingGroup(5));;`

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. This is a very intersting GAP-command. Having those generting sets of order two, is it also possible to get a (minimal) set of relations between them using GAP with a command?

Comment: There is `IsomorphismFpGroupByGenerators`, but it will returns just *a* presentation, neither nice, nor minimal.